# my div tag is not aligning properly after jquery.html replacement

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<div class="container"><span class="field_label">Job</span><input class="fields2" type="text" maxlength="200" name="first_name" /></div>
    <div class="container"><span class="field_label">Date</span><input class="fields2" type="text" maxlength="200" name="the_date" id="the_date" /></div>
    <div class="container" id="sched_text">sdfdsfdsf</div> <!-- schedule text-->
    <div class="container"><span class="field_label">Time</span>


.container{
position:relative;
display:block;
float:right;
border: 1px solid;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

my html/css here has my containers aligning right below each other. However, when I use .html in jquery to change or add text to sched_text it throws the css off and places the div tag not as a block anymore but placed somewhere to the side.

Does something change when you use .html text? what would the proper way of doing it? Thanks

Ok the issue is that my .html or .text is not a string. I just did .text(the_Week[i][1]); which results in a number. How do I present it as a string?

Comment: What are you seeing in Firebug or Chrome's inspector?  Are the classes and id's bound to the element?

Comment: yes it is. it's where the sdfdsfdsf should be. nothing has change except the text.

Comment: If your javascript code is causing this, you should include it in the question. Note also that the last `<div>` is not closed. Perhaps a copy/paste error? [Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2FxM7/) of your code (with the corrected closing tag). It works properly. Please updated it with an example that reflects your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest running your HTML through an HTML validator.  Sometimes HTML validation errors can cause unwanted or unexpected behavior.  Even without problems, this is always a good idea to avoid second-guessing when problems do occur.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/249/

If that doesn't work, maybe try using .text() to edit the text instead of .html().

Comment: Looks like there was indeed a validation issue in the code!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use float if you need them one below the other.. instead just put them inside bigger container with `text-align: right`:

```
<div style="text-align: right;">
    <div class="container"><span class="field_label">Job</span><input class="fields2" type="text" maxlength="200" name="first_name" /></div>
    <div class="container"><span class="field_label">Date</span><input class="fields2" type="text" maxlength="200" name="the_date" id="the_date" /></div>
    <div class="container" id="sched_text">sdfdsfdsf</div> <!-- schedule text-->
    <div class="container"><span class="field_label">Time</span></div>
</div>
```